# What would happen if Helen Magnus gave a normal human a blood transfusion?

Tags: sanctuary

Is there any grounds for an educated guess as to what would happen if Helen Magnus (or any of the core group: Tesla, Holmes, etc.) were to give a normal human like myself a blood transfusion? Would their blood impart any "source-blood attributes" to me?

It would seem that it CAN be transferred, as the Invisible Man's daughter could also go invisible.

Comment: Offspring and blood transfusion are kind of different, anyway..

Comment: True, one is an heterogeneous mixture, whereas the other is a genetic blending, I was just using that as a leaping-off point, not necessarily a direct example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 2 in-series examples:

- Helen Magnus was giving her blood to John Druitt - willingly or not - so that he could extend his life.  It's the sole reason he was still alive in our time period, when his ability did not give him an extended lifespan.  As shown in the series premiere, this was a raw blood transfusion, with no manipulation of Magnus's blood.
- Tesla experimented with using his blood as the basis for creating new vampires in 2x10, Sleepers.  It's unknown how much it was manipulated before the kids were injected, though.

So it seems to impart some mild form of their particular source-blood-acquired powers, temporary in Magnus's case and permanent in Tesla's case - although it may only have been permanent because Tesla managed to make it so in the kids, since they did actually die before they were "vamped".

Comment: Hmm, the Tesla kids are good examples, though as you said, Tesla was *brilliant* and could easily have altered it to impart traits. I missed the thing about Magnus giving Druitt transfusions though. To be fair though, in that case Druitt himself also had source-blood (even if it didn't give him longevity), so he's not really a "normal human" example.

Comment: @eidylon Ah, good point, I hadn't thought of that...  The only other source-blood-to-source-blood I can think of is when the Vampire Queen has some of Tesla's blood, but that's even less related..